# Implementing a Firebase Firestore synchronization & offline cache mechanism alike with custom API Rest endpoints

Tags: android, rest, client-server, android-syncadapter, data-synchronization

I am amazed how Firebase Firestore is dealing with synchronization & offline cache mechanism. Are there any resources out there that explain how to build something similar?

I thought about implementing something similar to a queue to store API Rest requests (that hasn't been sync) using a command design pattern. I wonder what's the best requests priority design guidelines.

I'm also interested on how to deal with the push mechanism from the server to the client.